# Selling UK inherited shares when resident abroad in a non permitted jurisdiction

Tags: united-kingdom, shares, international, selling, resident

I have recently inherited a small number of shares from my mother. These are held by COMPUTERSHARE on behalf of AVIVA. I am executor and sole beneficiary and am trying to liquidate the estate.
COMPUTERSHARE have sent me Bereavement Packs out but now inform that they cannot sell the shares as I am a non UK resident.
I have contacted a broker, as instructed by COMPUTERSHARE, but receive the same answer.
As a non-UK resident, how can I proceed further?

Comment: Have you asked them?

Comment: you may need an estate lawyer in the UK. I'm not UK based, but I know my parent's shares will be liquidated in their state of residence, with the proceeds going to the estate first. The estate is then divided up as appropriate. So, it does not matter where I live in that process, just where the estate is.